# Looking for a way of creating a cumulative average for individuals within a dataset

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

I have a dataset with multiple individuals (Cow_ID) and their daily difference in temperature looking like this:

```
df<-data.frame("Cow_ID"=c("192","192","192","192","201","201","201","201","652","652","652","652"),"Day"=c("1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4"),"Temp_Diff"=c("0.2","0.1","na","0.8","0.4","0.1","0.7","na","0.1","0.3","na","0.8"))
```

I want to calculate a cumulative mean for each individual in a new column. I need it to exclude the na's too.

I managed to get some code working to run this for the whole data set, but I could not find a way to get it to stop at the end of an individual and start again for the next one.

```
df<-df%>%mutate(new=replace(Temp_Diff,!is.na(Temp_Diff),cummean(Temp_Diff[!is.na(Temp_Diff)])))%>%fill(new)
```

Please excuse the sloppy coding, I am very new to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is by 'Cow_ID', then do a group by on that column.  Also, make sure to convert the `"na"` to `NA` before applying the `is.na` as well as convert the type as the 'Temp_Diff' column was `character` class as a result of "na" character element which doesn't work with `cummean`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  na_if("na") %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(Cow_ID) %>% 
  mutate(new = replace(Temp_Diff, !is.na(Temp_Diff), 
      cummean(Temp_Diff[!is.na(Temp_Diff)]))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 4
   Cow_ID   Day Temp_Diff    new
    <int> <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>
 1    192     1       0.2  0.2  
 2    192     2       0.1  0.15 
 3    192     3      NA   NA    
 4    192     4       0.8  0.367
 5    201     1       0.4  0.4  
 6    201     2       0.1  0.25 
 7    201     3       0.7  0.4  
 8    201     4      NA   NA    
 9    652     1       0.1  0.1  
10    652     2       0.3  0.2  
11    652     3      NA   NA    
12    652     4       0.8  0.4
```

---

Or using `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT`), conver the 'Temp_Diff' to `numeric` column with `as.numeric` returns `NA` for `"na"` while doing the force conversion, then create the 'new' column by specifying a logical condition in `i` to subset only the non-NA elements, do the `cummean` on 'j', grouped by 'Cow_ID' and assign (`:=`) to a new column 'new'

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[, Temp_Diff := as.numeric(Temp_Diff)][!is.na(Temp_Diff), 
      new := cummean(Temp_Diff), by = Cow_ID]
```

Comment: Though it works, please edit `ungroup` to `ungroup()`, It may look confusing.

Comment: @shafee you need `()` when you are specifying the namespace i.e. `dplyr::ungroup()` or else the functions can be invoked

Comment: Woah, learned a new thing. Thank you very much @akrun.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. I tried your code substituting in my actual data (much larger sheet with long-winded variable names) and am getting the following error:Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `new`.
i `new = replace(...)`.
i `new` must be size 9 or 1, not 1242.
i The error occurred in group 1: Cow_ID = 192.

Comment: @JenniferWeller What is the `nrow(yourdata)`.  If it is 1242, then change `mutate(` to `dplyr::mutate(`

Comment: Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `new`.
i `new = replace(...)`.
i `new` must be size 9 or 1, not 1242.
i The error occurred in group 1: Cow_ID = 192.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: @shafee My new code is: library(dplyr)
Offset_All_Data_4 %>% 
  na_if("na") %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(Offset_All_Data_4$Cow_ID) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(new = replace(Offset_All_Data_4$Left_Daily_Herd_Diff, !is.na(Offset_All_Data_4$Left_Daily_Herd_Diff), 
                       cummean(Offset_All_Data_4$Left_Daily_Herd_Diff[!is.na(Offset_All_Data_4$Left_Daily_Herd_Diff)]))) %>%
  ungroup()                       but the error remains :(

Comment: @JenniferWeller your code iss not exactly as I showed.  `Offset_All_Data_4$` would get the entire column within each group.  You don't need that part due to data masking.  i.e. `replace(Left_Daily_Herd_Diff, !is.na(Left_Daily_Herd_Diff), Left_Daily_Herd_Diff[!is.na(Left_Daily_Herd_Diff)])`

Comment: Thanks! So removing that has made the code run, but the averages do not seem to stopping within an individual. I was specifying the the data set as there are another 3 using the same variable names

Comment: @JenniferWeller Also the `group_by` code should be `group_by(Cow_ID)`

Comment: @JenniferWeller when you specify the group_by and using `Left_Daily_Herd_Diff`, it should do the cummean within each group id